# How to get people picker column user login name using CSOM in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom

currently i have ABC list with **People** column type[**Person or Group**]

i am trying to get user name from column using **CSOM** in Powershell script for SharePoint Online..

so please suggest some solutions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether user field is single or multi valued.

List item for `People column type[Person or Group]` has the following type in CSOM API:

- `Single`: [`FieldUserValue class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue.aspx)
- `Multi`: array of [`FieldUserValue class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue.aspx)

In turn `FieldUserValue class` does not expose login property (the list of properties could be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue_properties.aspx))

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve login property for `AssignedTo` (multi-valued) or `Author` (single-valued) user fields in `Tasks` list:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
$listTitle = "Tasks" #set List title 
#$fieldName = "AssignedTo"  #multi valued
$fieldName = "Author"  #single valued
$itemId = 1  #set List Item Id


$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$item = $list.GetItemById($itemId)
$context.Load($item)
$context.ExecuteQuery()


$userValue = $item.FieldValues[$fieldName]

if($userValue -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue]){  #Single user field value 

    $userItem = $context.Web.GetUserById($userValue.LookupId)
    $context.Load($userItem)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-Host $userItem.LoginName
}
else {

    foreach($userValuePart in $userValue) {

       $userItem = $context.Web.GetUserById($userValuePart.LookupId)
       $context.Load($userItem)
       $context.ExecuteQuery()

       Write-Host $userItem.LoginName
    }

}

$context.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}

Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $items 
}



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"


$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$items = Get-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle "Tasks" 
foreach($item in $items)
{
   $user = $item["AssignedTo"] 
        $userObj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $user) 
        $accountName = $userObj.User.UserLogin 
        $accountName.substring($accountName.IndexOf("\")+1)
        Write $accountName.substring($accountName.IndexOf("\")+1)
}
$context.Dispose()
```

Comment: i have using your code ,getting Error :-                                            New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SPFieldUserValue" and the argument count: "2".